# Is there a way in React Javascript to pass props and use it in external import?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, import, babeljs

I want to pass props from one component to another, and use it in the second one for an import above the component declaration

This is for using the same component, with no need to create it 4 times, every time with another SVG.

I'm using React, Javascript, Webpack, babel.
I'm also using svgr/webpack to create a component from an SVG picture, and it's crucial for me to use SVG not < img >.

```
import React from 'react';
import RightNavItem from './right_nav_item';

const RightNav = ({navitems}) => {
  const rightNavItems = navitems.map( (item) => {
    return <RightNavItem name={ item }/>
  });

  return(
    <div className="rightnav">
      {rightNavItems}
    </div>
  );
};
```

.

```
export default RightNav;

import React from 'react';

const RightNavItem = ({ name }) => {
  const svgpath = `../../../../resources/img/navbar/${name}.svg`;
  return(
    <div>
      <img src={ svgpath } style={{height: '25px'}}/>
      <span>{ name }</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RightNavItem;
```

And I want to achieve being able to do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgPicture from '../../../../resources/img/navbar/{name}.svg';

const RightNavItem = ({ name }) => {
    return(
      <div>
        <SvgPicture />
        <span>{ name }</span>
      </div>
    );
};

export default RightNavItem;
```

.

Comment: You can use a context to reduce the need for prop drilling: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I don't think javascript supports dynamic imports like this, yet. You might be able to use require(path/to/svg) in the render function of the SvgComponent. If so, then you could pass the path as a prop.

Comment: Check out [create-react-app docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) section named **Adding SVGs** you are not using create-react-app but you can have an idea about the solution

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to do it, in a bit ugly way, but did it.
I used {props.children}, and instead of using map(), I added the <RightNavItem> 4 times, each with different 'SVG' component child and different props 'name', that way the component only gets initialized at the RightNavItem level. I'll comment with the solution, hoping someone can tell me how I can manage to do it with map(). Thanks again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I went back and implemented the whole thing on my local app to get exactly what you need. I am editing my original answer. Hope this solves your issue.

The parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as svg } from 'assets/img/free_sample.svg';
import RightNavItem from './RightNavItem';

const LOGOS = [
 { name: 'home', svg },
 { name: 'home', svg },
];

const RightNav = () => (
 <div>
  {LOGOS.map(logo => (
    <RightNavItem name={logo.name}>
      <logo.svg />
    </RightNavItem>
   ))}
 </div>
);

export default RightNav;
```

The child:

```
import React from 'react';

const RightNavItem = ({ name, children }) => (
 <div>
  {children}
  <span>{name}</span>
 </div>
);

export default RightNavItem;
```

You don't need to import the svg as I did, if you are able to use svg as a component in your webpack config then continue to do what you were doing before.

Comment: Hey Hasan, thanks for your answer.
I tried something similar to what you're suggesting but that didn't work.
Maybe I was doing it wrong.
I tried to import (above RightNav) all the SVG's (so now they are React Components), pass it in props to RightNavItem, on each iteration the appropriate, and then use it.
But for some reason I get thrown with this error coming up in the console:
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]=

I did not mention I'm new to React.

Comment: No worries @YossiSaadi all of us are learning here. So the error you are getting is a very common one. Objects can't be used as react components. But what you can do is something like this. For example if you have the object from svgAsset. then you can do this <item.value /> . React will allow this if you have configured webpack correctly. So again, just pass the whole object to <RightNavItem /> and try the mentioned method.

Comment: Also from your error I see that you are using production build. You should be using development build. May be try using create-react-scripts. Specially for new people it makes things much easier!

Comment: @YossiSaadi Please have a look at the following link. This shows how you can import svg both as a source or as a component.
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

May be using src would be easier.

Comment: Hasan, I can't use src cause I need to use fill and stroke in the CSS of the SVG component. I managed to do it in kind of the way you suggested at the comments here.
I used {props.children}, and instead of using map(), I added the <RightNavItem> 4 times, each with different 'SVG' component child and different props 'name', that way the component only gets initialized at the RightNavItem level. Thanks you really really helped me !

Comment: @YossiSaadi I have run this on local and it works, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in a kind of ugly way, but it works.
The problem is if I have more than 4 items, then using it without the map() function can be really annoying.

I used {props.children}, and instead of using map(), I added the  4 times, each with different 'SVG' component child and different props 'name', that way the component only gets initialized at the RightNavItem level.

IF SOMEONE KNOWS how can I use this with the map() function, It'll help a lot!
Thanks to everyone who helped!

For example:

```
const RightNav = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className = "rightnav">
      <RightNavItem name = {home}>
        <HomeSVG />
      </RightNavItem>

      <RightNavItem name = {profile}>
         <ProfileSVG />
      </RightNavItem>
      .
      .
      .
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the RightNavItem:

```
const RightNavItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {props.children}
      <span>{ props.name }</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```